# Rule regarding the pseudo-inverse

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

While inverting the structure like $A^TDA$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, $n > p$, with rank $p$, and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix.

Do we have the following equation
$$(A^TDA)^{-1}=A^{+}D^{-1}(A^{T})^+$$, where $(\cdot)^+$ means the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse of the matrix.

Comment: @b00nheT Sorry I made a serious typo! Now it can inverse.

Comment: Do you really want $D$ to be nonsingular? Is the inverse in the left side supposed to be a +? If $D$ is the identity matrix, I don't think $AA^\top$ necessarily is invertible.

Comment: @rschwieb If that is the case, since $A$ has full row rank, $A^+=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}, (A^T)^+=(AA^T)^{-1}A, (AA^T)^+=(A^T)^+A^+$

Comment: @omg-256 ... does this mean you are assuming $A^\top DA$ has full rank then?

Comment: @rschwieb I think when $A$ has full row rank, which is $p$ here, $A^TDA$ will have a full rank $p$.

Comment: @omg-256 Not if $D$ is zero. Or has a zero eigenvalue.

Comment: @rschwieb Well let's say D is a diagonal matrix with each diagonal entries larger than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional assumptions about $D$ being nonsingular and the rows of $A$ having full row rank are strong enough to apply the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Products) a couple of times, which yields

$$A^{+}D^{-1}(A^\top)^+=A^+D^+(A^\top)^+=(A^\top DA)^+=(A^\top DA)^{-1}$$

<s>Conversely, the existence of the inverse on the right implies $D$ is nonsingular and that $A$ has full row rank.</s> Reconsidering...

Comment: Great, thank you! When I tried it on Matlab, I found that the result of left and right are not exactly the same, I thought it might be caused by some numerical error, but once it is theoretically sound, I can plug it into my proof.

Comment: @omg-256 you know what would be really slick: do an error analysis of your calculation, and do experimental runs to prove that you can predict attribute the error you're seeing in terms of machine epsilon. He. You really can be convinced its rounding errors.

Comment: I'm confused. The OP said that $A$ is $n\times p$ with $n>p$, so $A$ cannot possibly have full row rank. And you said that *"the existence of the inverse on the right implies ... $A$ has full row rank"*. Shouldn't this imply that $A$ has full **column** rank instead?

Comment: @user1551 I'm not sure why you think $A$ can't have full row rank. The rank might be $p$ or it might not be $p$, both are possible. But I see what you're saying about the row-column rank problem. I was basing this on the [hypotheses for the product rule in the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Products). Either the article has the two reversed, or I need to retract the last sentence. I'll look for alternative resources to see which one is the case...

Comment: @rschwieb Oh, I see. We understand the phrase "full row rank" differently. You take it to mean the row rank is equal to the smaller of the two dimensions, but I take it to mean the row rank is equal to the number of rows.

Comment: @user1551 Yeah, I think I've forgotten the right usage for nonsquare matrices. For square matrices one never has to worry about mixing things up... I will have to make sure I interpreted the wiki article correctly in that light.

Comment: @user1551 Well, based on another primary source it looks like the wiki article is fine. Maybe this doesn't work out after all??!

Comment: @omg-256 Hope you are following this... It looks like the product rule won't apply unless you have $p \geq n$ instead... But then the problem seems to be that $A^\top D A$ can't be invertible...

Comment: Interesting, really good to know that it might not work. So tricky the rule is.Thanks!

Comment: @omg-256 how big were the errors?